# Number of Tags of NER

Tags: java, machine-learning, nlp, stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition

As far as I know, Stanford NER has 3,4 and 7 class models (or tags).
I need a standard and a Java implementation of a Named Entity Recognizer which has more than 7 tags (for example 13 tags). I don’t want to develop it by myself and I need it to be accurate. Is there any NER which satisfies these conditions?

Thanks

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

The Stanford NER system can be retrained for any number of tags. The 3, 4, and 7 class models are just the pre-trained models. If you'd like to train it on more classes, you'd have to collect training data with those classes in it, and retrain the model.

Answer (score 1):

Python [nltk](http://opennlp.apache.org/) package provide Named Entity Recognition(NER), it have an in build classifier. It have more than 7 classes. Which are

```
ORGANIZATION - Georgia-Pacific Corp., WHO
PERSON - Eddy Bonte, President Obama
LOCATION - Murray River, Mount Everest
DATE - June, 2008-06-29
TIME - two fifty a m, 1:30 p.m.
MONEY - 175 million Canadian Dollars, GBP 10.40
PERCENT - twenty pct, 18.75 %
FACILITY - Washington Monument, Stonehenge
GPE - South East Asia, Midlothian
```

You are using `Java`,so there is an equivalent package in `java` which is [OpenNLP](http://opennlp.apache.org/) . You can check the classifier in `OpenNLP`.

Here is the SO [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15478263/java-equivalent-for-python-nltk) which proves `OpenNLP` is equivalent to `nltk`